# Binding doesn't appear on label on XAML

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have these lines of code on my XAML

```
    <ContentPage.BindingContext>
        <x:Reference Name="messagesPage" />
    </ContentPage.BindingContext>

    ....

  <Label Text="{Binding ConversationPartner.contactName[0]}" FontSize="Title" TextColor="Black"
                           VerticalOptions="Center" FontAttributes="Bold" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand">
                        <Label.Triggers>
                            <DataTrigger TargetType="Label" Binding="{Binding ConversationPartner.contactID[1], Converter={StaticResource isViewerConverter}}" Value="False">
                                <Setter Property="Text"  Value="{Binding ConversationPartner.contactName[1]}"/>
                            </DataTrigger>
                        </Label.Triggers>
                    </Label>
```

What I want to happen is that a name on the label represented by ConversationPartner.contactName[0] must appear on my application but it doesn't.

Here's the code behind

```
public partial class MessagesPage : ContentPage
{
        DataClass dataClass = DataClass.GetInstance;
        public ICommand CloseMsg => new Command(async () => await Navigation.PopModalAsync(true));
        public ICommand SendCommand => new Command(Send);
        
        ContactModel ConversationPartner;
        public MessagesPage(ContactModel input)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            NavigationPage.SetHasNavigationBar(this, false);
            ConversationsList = new ObservableCollection<ConversationModel>();
            ConversationPartner = input;
            /// some cloud firestore code here
        }
}
```

Comment: I don't think you can bind arrays like that...

Comment: you can only bind to **public properties** - `ConversationPartner` is neither public nor a C# property

Comment: @Jason Is there a definitive way on how I can bind ConversationPartner without actually changing the way it was defined?

Comment: `public ContactModel ConversationPartner { get; set; }`

Comment: @Jason Although I did not get any errors, there is still no text displayed on the label. The binding didn't work.

Comment: is `contactName` an array or IEnumerable?  Why are you using any indexer?

Comment: contact name is defined as string[] _contactName in my model. contactName[0], contactName[1] are the participants of the conversation

Comment: are they also public properties?  Please post your model

Comment: @Jason Yes. Found a solution already by using observable collection. Posted it as an answer too.

Answer (score 1):

Found a solution.

I made an observable collection so that I could bind easily.
My code behind:

```
     public MessagesPage(ContactModel input)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            NavigationPage.SetHasNavigationBar(this, false);
            ConversationsList = new ObservableCollection<ConversationModel>();
            convoers = new ObservableCollection<string> {input.contactName[0], input.contactName[1], input.contactID[1] };
            ConversationPartner = input;
            ...
        }
```

then in my XAML,

```
 <Label Text="{Binding convoers[0]}" FontSize="Title" TextColor="Black"
                           VerticalOptions="Center" FontAttributes="Bold" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand">
                        <Label.Triggers>
                            <DataTrigger TargetType="Label" Binding="{Binding convoers[2], Converter={StaticResource isViewerConverter}}" Value="False">
                                <Setter Property="Text"  Value="{Binding convoers[1]}"/>
                            </DataTrigger>
                        </Label.Triggers>
                    </Label>
```